# Multiple NServiceBus hosts in single windows service

Tags: nservicebus

I have a database which has a number of queues which will contain messages from a 3rd party product.  I would like to import these messages onto my Bus for processing and believe that I can achieve this with NServiceBus but I would like to host all the message importing within a single Windows Service that will have configuration on the database queue to monitor.

The processing steps are as follows:

1) Import onto Bus
2) transform into message
3) Send Bus message

Each NServiceBus would be configured to poll the database queue periodically.  When a message arrives it will perform a Bus.SendLocal to perform step 1.

The NSB host would then receive process with a message handler.  Within this message handler the transformation of the message would occur.  Finally, the actually Bus message would be sent.  Usual config would deal with the destination host.

I would like to understand whether multiple NSB hosts can be placed within a single Windows Service and if there are any issues associated with this?  I believe that all hosts would need to share the same configuration (I am happy of this restriction), is that correct?

If multiple hosts is a 'no-no', my alternative is to have a Window Service with a Bus reference (singleton).  A TPL task would monitor the database queue and then use the Bus to import the database message.  A separate NServiceBus would handle or the imported database messages and perform the transformation and sending to other hosts.

Sorry about the length of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a Satellite to perform those kinds of DB queries and then forward onto the bus.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "hosts"?  Do you mean can one endpoint handle many different message types?

You can handle as many different message types as you want in a single host.  The only restriction is that they will share the same queue, which means that all message types will be given the same priority (which is only a problem in very specific cases).

Comment: Hi, sorry about the confusion.  A host would have the following capability:  1) Monitor a database queue, 2) A reference to the Bus to post messages, 3) The ability to have a Message Handler class for processing the messages before sending out to the Bus.  Each thread would contain an instance of an NServiceBus host

Comment: I am aware that I can have as many message handlers in 1 host by adding IHandleMessages.  This question is whether, in a single Windows Process, I can (or should) host multiple NServiceBus hosts, each on a separate thread or can (or should) I put each within it's own service?

Comment: I'm still not clear on why would you need separate hosts (and maybe that's your question).  I think you just want multiple background threads that monitor the database and then send commands (or publish events) to the bus.